# Make help command print the commands unsorted

Tags: python, discord.py

Trying to figure out how to use this attribute: [sort_commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=sort_commands#discord.ext.commands.DefaultHelpCommand.sort_commands)

Seems like it's there so that I can change its default (`True`) to `False` but I can't figure out how to do it.

So far everyone has suggested for me to use `bot.remove_command("help")` and then implement my own from scratch.

But it seems like it's missing something. This attribute exists for a reason, doesn't it? Must be a better way to use this attribute rather than implement an entire command from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do what I intended in the following way:

I created my own help command which extends (inherits) from `DefaultHelpCommand`, then I overriden the `send_bot_help` coroutine and change the sorting to compare by the command `description` field instead of command name field (I preferred creating my own `order` field or such, but couldn't find the right way to do it, so I used an existing field).

Then I order my commands like this:

```
@commands.command(help="A helpful description of cmd1", name="commandName", description='1')
@commands.command(help="A helpful description of cmd2", name="commandName2", description='2')
```

Following is the class:

```
class MyHelpCommand(DefaultHelpCommand):
    async def send_bot_help(self, mapping):
       # ... everything up here copy-pased from original superclass
                                 # This used to be c.name
       commands = sorted(commands, key=lambda c: c.description)
       # ... The rest is also copy-pasted
```

Then I use it like suggested:

```
help_command = MyHelpCommand()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=Config.COMMAND_PREFIX, help_command=help_command)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're able to create a new instance of a default help command:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

help_command = commands.DefaultHelpCommand(sort_commands=False) # Also set other options here

# And pass in the new help command into the bot so it knows to use it
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", help_command=help_command)
```

---

**References:**

- [`Bot.help_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.help_command)
- [`commands.DefaultHelpCommand()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.DefaultHelpCommand) - See other options you can edit in here.

Comment: Excellent, this seems much more what I was aiming for. Small question, where do you recommend using the code you suggested? Is there a particular place it fits properly or will any class do? (Sorry if it is a basic question, I'm rather new to the framework).

Comment: Just plonk it into your main script where you created your `bot` or `client` instance. Also, if you're using `discord.Client()`, I'd highly recommend switching to `commands.Bot()` - it inherits from `discord.Client()` and it also allows you to do other funky stuff like in the answer ^. I'll happy edit my answer if you need me to :) @Nom1fan

Comment: I've found it, thanks for your help ! Finally a good helper :) I will test it now and mark it as answer if it works.

Comment: Well it seems to have done something since the order changed :) So I marked it as answer. Though it didn't quite do what I thought (imagined it would print in the order the commands appear in code). If you have the will and time to help me further, is there a way I can control the order (again without writing the command from scratch)?

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I'm not actually all too sure what controls the order of unsorted commands, but I'll take a look into it. At first I thought it was the length of the command name, but that doesn't seem to affect anything. @Nom1fan - It seems to change each time I restart the bot.

Comment: Ok, I guess it requires something more advanced like inheriting from `DefaultHelpCommand` and overriding the `send_bot_help` function and implementing some custom sorting strategy. A lot of work for cosmetics but I'll give it a shot at some point. Thanks for all your help !